# Access Apache server installed on a VM remotely from computer in local network

Tags: apache, virtual-machine, vagrant

I would like to access Apache from a computer that is inside my network, the problem is Apache is running on a virtual machine:

DIAGRAM

```
(  [A: VM Running Apache] -- [B: Actual machine]  ) ------ [C: Actual machine]
```

IP's:

```
A: 192.168.55.55
B: 192.168.1.25
```

I can access A from B just fine, but not from C. (I get a message that reads 'the connection to the server timed out' after a while).

B: NETWORK INFO

[image]

PD: The reason Apache is inside a VM is because I'm using Vagrant, not sure that has something to do with anything but I thought I'd mention it anyways.

Comment: Yes!. Sorry, I am using VirtualBox. Let me add some more info to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to get this working on my home network.

On the machine actually running Vagrant, edit the Vagrantfile and port forward **8088** (or whatever port # you choose) from the Host ('Actual Machine' as you called it) to port **80** on the Guest ('VM Running Apache' as you called it).

Do a normal **vagrant up** and you should see the port forwarding happening on boot up.  I personally have approximately 8 virtual hosts running inside my Vagrant box each with their own host name.  I edited my hosts file on the Host (machine 'B' above) in order to point these hostnames to the ip of the Vagrant box.  It works great and I can just put in something like **mysite.dev** in the address bar and that site pulls up on my local machine.

Now to get this to work on another machine, within the same subnet as the Host machine, you will need to edit the hosts file on that second machine.  Point the hostnames, my example was **mysite.dev**, to the actual ip address of the Host machine.  This will forward any instance of **mysite.dev** to the machine you have labeled as 'B' in your question.  The only problem is that this is just pointing to the standard port **80** like any normal webpage.  You want this traffic to actually get to machine 'A' in your question.  So instead of just putting **mysite.dev** into the address bar of the browser, put **mysite.dev:8088** (or whatever port number you chose to forward to machine 'A' earlier).

Now the traffic from 'C' will be sent to machine 'B' because the hosts file tells it to go there and the additional port you added to the address forces machine 'B' to forward that traffic to port **80** on machine 'A'.  Machine 'A' receives the request and returns the data to machine 'B' which then forwards it back to machine 'C'.

The end result is machine 'C' seeing the page returned from machine 'A'.

Hope that about sums it all up.

Good luck!

c0p

Comment: Thanks! :) this is exactly what I needed, I figured out that I wasn't being able to enter access the VM because I wasn't specifying the port. Editing the host file is a great idea :)

Answer (score 1):

If your Vagrant version is >= 1.5 and using a public url doesn't create concerns, the solution should be trivial:

```
vagrant share
```

More info [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/http.html).

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful; but it is not quite what I want to do, it comes close though. I don't want to make my server available to anyone on the internet, just my private network.